# Split Values into several other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sqlfiddle

Code :

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  day DATE,
  name VARCHAR(40)
  );
INSERT INTO table1 (day, name)
VALUES 
('2018-01-01', 'test1'),
('2018-01-01', 'test2'),
('2018-01-01', 'example'),
('2018-01-01', 'somevalue'),
('2018-01-02', 'test3'),
('2018-01-03', 'test4');
```

I want to split the result into something like :

```
day - name1 - name2 - namex  
DATE - value - value - value
```

instead of duplicating the date when I select data.

EXPECTED RESULT :

```
day - name - name - name - name ...
2018-01-01 - test1 - test2 - example - somevalue
2018-01-02 - NULL - NULL - NULL - NULL - test3
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba2c78/1/0)

Comment: Please give sample table data and the expected result as formatted text as well.

Comment: since the `name` has variable length, this is not possible. You should go with `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT`. Check this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba2c78/5)

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Strawberry You mean like with another language like php ?

Comment: I've edited the sample table data. Now show us the expected result.

Comment: @Thank you for the fiddle, I guess I can go from this and adapt it to build a chart with Chartjs since this is the objective

Comment: @jarlh I added the expected result

Comment: What's the purpose of this ? For example if you have 1000 rows then you will have 1000 columns in result ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via dynamic sql, firstly finding the distinct name values then and building the rest of the code around them for example

given

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+------------+-----------+
| day        | name      |
+------------+-----------+
| 2018-01-01 | test      |
| 2018-01-01 | test      |
| 2018-01-01 | example   |
| 2018-01-01 | somevalue |
| 2018-01-02 | test      |
| 2018-01-03 | test      |
+------------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

set @sql = concat('select day, ',
(select group_concat(maxstr)
from
(select concat('max(case when name = ', char(39),name,char(39),' then  name else null end) as ', concat('name',@rn:=@rn+1)) maxstr
from  
(select distinct name from t) t,(select @rn:=0) rn
) s
)
,
' from t group by day')
;
```

builds this code

```
select day, max(case when name = 'test' then  name else null end) as name1,
        max(case when name = 'example' then  name else null end) as name2,
        max(case when name = 'somevalue' then  name else null end) as name3 
from t group by day;
```

Which yields this result when run

```
+------------+-------+---------+-----------+
| day        | name1 | name2   | name3     |
+------------+-------+---------+-----------+
| 2018-01-01 | test  | example | somevalue |
| 2018-01-02 | test  | NULL    | NULL      |
| 2018-01-03 | test  | NULL    | NULL      |
+------------+-------+---------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The advantage of using dynamic sql is that it's pretty much fire and forget any new values will be caught by the code. Be careful of the group_concat limit though.

Execute dynamic sql like this-

```
prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
execute sqlstmt;
deallocate prepare sqlstmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code you Group By Day and Name and Sorted this with Ascending

```
SELECT * FROM table1
group by day, name
ORDER BY day ASC;
```

Check on [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqmY8.jpg)

Comment: Not exactly what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using group by and group concat as  per below

```
select t.day,left(t.data,length(t.data)-1)
from
(
SELECT day,replace(group_concat(concat(name,'-')),',','')as data
FROM table1
group by day
  )t
```